# ggplot raster and contour not work

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster, contour, r-raster

**ENV**

R 3.3.2

---

I am plotting raster contour plot using ggplot follow [sample code](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_contour.html):

```
library(ggplot2)
v <- ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions, z = density))
v + geom_raster(aes(fill = density)) +
    geom_contour(colour = "white")
```

[image]

---

My code and mini data is:

```
pdf(file="graster.pdf")
par(mfrow=c(2,2))

library(ggplot2)
v <- ggplot(faithfuld, aes(waiting, eruptions, z = density))
v + geom_raster(aes(fill = density)) +
    geom_contour(colour = "white")
#print(faithfuld)

#####  below: my code ########

b<-c(0.8,1.8,2.8) 
p<-c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9) 

nvalue<-c(
    0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
    0.3, 0.2, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5,
    0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.5, 0.6, 0.6, 0.6, 0.7, 0.7
)

myarray<-array(nvalue, c(length(p), length(b)), dimnames=list(p,b))
odftarget<-as.data.frame.table(myarray) # change to data.frame
names(odftarget) <- c('p', 'b', 'v')
dftarget <- data.frame(  # restore to new data.frame without factor
    p=as.numeric(as.character(odftarget$p)),
    b=as.numeric(as.character(odftarget$b)), 
    v=odftarget$v
)
head(dftarget) 
library(tibble)
tdftarget<-as_tibble(dftarget)  # change to tibble
v <- ggplot(tdftarget, aes(b, p, z = density))  # same plot method as the sample code
v + geom_raster(aes(fill = density)) +
    geom_contour(colour = "white")
```

---

My code get Error:

```
Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type function. Defaulting to continuous.
Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  :
```

---

I think my data have same format with the sample data `faithfuld`. And they all stores in a `tibble` object.

I don't have any clue about the problem. Thanks for your consideration.

Comment: You have no `density` column in you data. `aes(b, p, z = v)` should do the trick. And there is no need to transform to a `tibble`.

Comment: Yes, definitely.  Thank you.